# Canvas scroll animation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm building a gantt chart style timeline using html canvas element.

I am currently attempting to add the functionality which allows the user to click a next/prev button to have the gantt chart scroll to display earlier or later times.

The way I am doing this is to have a span.adjustTime where the id holds a value in seconds for the time to be adjusted (eg 86400 for one day).

I am trying to animate the scrolling so it looks like a scroll, rather than jumping ahead by one day.

I have a small problem in my timing calculation, but the script below is not animating, but rather jumping directly to the final time.

I do have the draw function running on a separate setInterval which updates every second, so I'm hoping it isn't an issue of conflicting timers on the same function on the same element and data.

```
jQuery('span.adjustTime').click(function() {

    var adjustBy = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('a', ''));
    var data = jQuery('img#logo').data();

    for(var m = 1; m >= 30; m++) {
        gantt.startUnixTime = gantt.startUnixTime + (adjustBy * (m * 0.001));

        var moveTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            draw(document.getElementById('gantt'), data, gantt);

        }, 1000);

        if (m == 30) {
            clearTimeout(moveTimer);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop you are calling `setTimeout` 30 times, each time with the same timeout value of 1000. So after 1000 milliseconds 30 scheduled functions will execute at almost the same time. I suppose this is not what you intended. If you wanted an animation of 30 frames over 1000 milliseconds, the setTimeout should look something like:

```
setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1000 / 30 * m)
```

Also note that all 30 scheduled functions will see the same `gantt.startUnixTime` value, since the same object (`gantt`) is passed to all of them, and when they execute, the for loop has finished already long ago.